# Postgresql CTE perfomance issues

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, common-table-expression, postgresql-11

I'm having perfomance issues using CTE in query.

These queries are large, but the only difference between them is number of IDs listen inside `IN` clause.

First one contains 2000 IDs inside `IN` clause, second one only 1000.

Execution time of first one is about 33s, second - 500ms.

I've also tried to increase/decrease amount of IDs, but wasn't able to find critical number where perfomance drops.

3000 IDs - 36s

4000 IDs - 39s

So it doesn't grow lineary, somewhere between 1000 and 2000 IDs is that critical spot, but what is the cause?

Analysis for them:

**First (slow one)**

https://gist.github.com/DonKeyHot1/7251adab3ca589c55ebead2ba75fbcf1

**Second (fast one)**

https://gist.github.com/DonKeyHot1/48d85eaeeb84316bb43adf50114914d3

(They are too large to post them here)

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Instead of using CTEs, put the ids into a temporary table with the `id` in the table as the primary key:

```
create table temp_ids (
    id int primary key
);
```

This should help the optimizer generate a good execution plan.